# Why does sharing PHP sessions between concurrently open pages seem to work in FF, but not IE or Chrome?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, session, cookies

**EDIT I just realized that I must have had a massive brain fart while writing the abbreviated code sample.  See, I'm using smarty.  Thus, I'm actually already using Kips's solution, because smarty displays after the session is saved**

I've been working on implementing a resource manager (for condensing, compressing and minifying CSS & JS) for a PHP site I'm working on and have run into an awfully strange problem.  So when a user navigates to index.php, files are added to a resource manager object, which combines them into a single file and are included in the page via either `<script src="resource.php?id=123&ext=.js">` or `<link href="resource.php?id=123&ext=.css" />`

What it basically boils down to is that a file path is stored in a session on the accessed page and read from the session on the resource page.  In FF, this works perfectly fine.  In IE and Chrome, it does not.

Here's a much-abbreviated code sample:

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
//Do a ton of stuff
//Including adding several files to the resource object
//Add the resource links to the head
$smarty->append('headSection','<link href="resource.php?id=<?=$resourceID?>&type=.js" />');
</head>
//Save the resource file which:
// - Outputs the file
// - Saves a reference to it in session
$_SESSION[$resourceID] = $file;
//Let Smarty display
$smarty->display($templateFile);
?>
```

**resource.php**

```
<?php
readfile($_SESSION[$_GET['id']] . $_GET['type']);
?>
```

What it seems like to me is that FF waits for an entire page response before making any new requests to the resources required by the page, while IE and Chrome function by starting a new request the second it is encountered.  Due to this, this error basically boils down to a race condition.

Can anyone confirm that this is indeed the way it works?  And if so - how would I work around it?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you're doing, and where?  A couple of code snippets along with an explanation of where they happen would be helpful.

Comment: @Nate: in addition to my answer below, I'd also make sure that you are clearing cookies and cache and restarting the browser before each test.  if you aren't doing that, it could be that it works because you already have a session in FF but not in the other browsers.

Comment: @Kip: I clear cache often enough in IE and Chrome to get around that and it's always a ctrl-shift-r in FF.
@timdev: Yea, I know... how's that?

Comment: Save the resource file before outputting the href that refers to it.  But more importantly, don't use sessions for this -- if someone opens multiple pages in tabs simultaneously, you're probably going to run into problems.

Comment: @Nate: after seeing your update, I'm actually surprised that it *is* working in FF.  I edited my answer with a different suggestion.

Comment: @Frank Farmer: I work around the multiple page issue by generating a guid for the object.  The reason it uses sessions is to actually establish the relationship between that guid and a (potentially) cached resource file.  I wish I could save the resource file before outputting the href, but the framework has so many parts that are already established, it's not all that practical.  (This is also why it uses a guid rather than the resource filename as a identifier)

Comment: @Kip: I think I solved the mystery of why it works in FF... But I also made a new mystery as to why it doesn't work.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: After the update to your question, then I am not surprised that you are getting a race condition.  I don't know why it is working in Firefox, but IE and Chrome are certainly not doing anything illegal by requesting the resources early.  One way you could resolve this is with output buffering.  At the top of your index.php file, you can add:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

This kills two birds with one stone, by: a) making sure that output is buffered, so the browser doesn't see the file until the whole page has been generated; and b) saving you and your users bandwidth by using gzip compression.

---

**Previous answer**: That doesn't seem to make sense.  Cookies can only be set in the header, which happens before any page content is loaded.  So the browser requests index.php, and the PHPSESSID cookie is set in the header.  Then the page content is delivered.

I don't have access to a machine with PHP at the moment, but the following might help to test your theory.  `test1.php` sets a session variable, but then takes 30 seconds to completely finish loading.  Meanwhile, `test2.php` (a CSS file) will try to use that session variable as the text color.  The text will show up red if the session could be read from test2, or black (default color) otherwise.

**test1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['mycolor'] = 'red';
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.php" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
Starting test...<br/>
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) //loop will take 30 seconds to complete
{
  echo "$i<br/>\n";
  sleep(5);
}
?>
Done!
</body>
</html>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
body { color: <?php echo $_SESSION['mycolor']; ?>; }
```

Comment: At first I thought it was how browsers handled cookies, I've since squashed that theory and think that it's related to the order in which stuff is loaded.  Basically like if you moved your `$_SESSION['mycolor'] = 'red';` to at the bottom of test1.php and added a `sleep(2);`

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was needed to fix this.  For starters, Kip's suggested solution is correct, however it wasn't actually the solution to my problem as what I said was my problem wasn't actually my problem... more or less.

In one of the tests I was doing, I noticed suddenly that the SessionID was different for the page and for the resource file.  I didn't have any idea how that was possible, until I remembered that in another component that I include in the page, I regenerate the SessionID (`session_regenerate_id()`) to prevent CSRF attacks.  Once I commented out that line, everything worked perfectly in every browser.

For me however, this raises a new question...  Why isn't session_regenerate_id() preserving session data?

**Edit - Follow up:**
It seems that this is actually a known issue and is well documented in the comments on the PHP docs page for session_regenerate_id().

Start here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php#81212 and read up.